# C/C++ Access violation writing when changing array value

Tags: c, memory, runtime-error, access-violation

This will be a foolishness, but this code to change the Drive letter of the Wide-String throws me an Acces violation when writting the new value. (0xC0000005)

```
wchar_t* disk2 = L"D";
wchar_t* wszDrive = L"\\\\.\\C:";
wszDrive[5] = *disk2; //here is the acces violation
```

I'm using the lattest version of Visual Studio 2019.

Also I tried this way:

```
wchar_t* disk2 = L"D";
wchar_t* wszDrive = L"\\\\.\\C:";
memcpy(&wszDrive[5], disk2, 2);
```

And this other way:

```
wchar_t* disk2 = L"D";
wchar_t* wszDrive = L"\\\\.\\C:";
memcpy(wszDrive+10, disk2, 2);
```

Comment: C/C++? Is that a new language?

Comment: `wchar_t wszDrive[] = L"\\\\.\\C:";`